# Use of FilenameFilter

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

I have a directory:

```
File dir = new File(MY_PATH);
```

I would like to list all the files whose name is indicated as integer numbers strings, e.g. "10", "20". 
I know I should use:

```
dir.list(FilenameFilter filter);
```

How to define my `FilenameFilter`?

**P.S.** I mean the file name could be any integer string, e.g. "10" or "2000000" or "3452345". No restriction in the number of digits as long as the file name is a integer string.

Comment: I've never done this before but 10 seconds on google says that you should do `new FileNameFilter()` and then implement an anonymous inner class to choose what file names you should accept.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should *override* [`accept`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html#accept%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) in the *interface* [`FilenameFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html#accept%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) and make sure that the parameter `name` has only numeric chars. You can check this by using [`matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] list = dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.matches("[0-9]+");
    }
});
```

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon unless you cannot (e.g., prefix is coming as an input parameter)

Comment: is it possible if I change hte array type to File[] instead of String[]?

Answer (score 9):

preferably as an instance of an anonymous inner class passsed as parameter to [File#list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29).

for example, to list only files ending with the extension `.txt`:

```
File dir = new File("/home");
String[] list = dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
    }
});
```

To list only files whose filenames are integers of exactly 2 digits you can use the following in the accept method:

```
return name.matches("\\d{2}");
```

for one or more digits:

```
return name.matches("\\d+");
```

**EDIT** (as response to @crashprophet's comment)

Pass a set of extensions of files to list

```
class ExtensionAwareFilenameFilter implements FilenameFilter {

    private final Set<String> extensions;

    public ExtensionAwareFilenameFilter(String... extensions) {
        this.extensions = extensions == null ? 
            Collections.emptySet() : 
                Arrays.stream(extensions)
                    .map(e -> e.toLowerCase()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return extensions.isEmpty() || 
            extensions.contains(getFileExtension(name));
    }

    private String getFileExtension(String filename) {
        String ext = null;
        int i = filename .lastIndexOf('.');
        if(i != -1 && i < filename .length()) {
            ext = filename.substring(i+1).toLowerCase();
        }
        return ext;
    }
}


@Test
public void filefilter() {
    Arrays.stream(new File("D:\\downloads").
        list(new ExtensionAwareFilenameFilter("pdf", "txt")))
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
}
```

Comment: I need to filter out files to get only files with name contain integer numbers as string, no extention. E.g. "10" , "20"

Comment: How would you go about parameterizing the endsWith(parameter) call? If I wanted toto search for .txt or .pdf in certain circumstances, how would I do that?

Comment: @crashprophet by create an own class implementing `FilenameFilter` and passing it the extensions you want to filter by. The argument for the `File#list` methos is no longer an anonymous class but an instance of the new class you have created. See code sample.

Comment: Thanks A4L, I ended up doing something like the following:private final String filter;

     public FilterAwareFilenameFilter(String filter) {
         this.filter = filter;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
         return filter.toLowerCase().endsWith(this.filter);
     }    // I don't know what I was doing before but it works now after your example!

Answer (score 8):

Since Java 8, you can simply use a lambda expression to specify your custom filter:

```
dir.list((dir1, name) -> name.equals("foo"));
```

In the above example, only files with the name "foo" will make it through. Use your own logic of course.

Comment: how to specify a pattern here instead of equal() method?

Comment: @gaurav just use the `matches` method like this: `dir.list((dir1, name) -> name.matches("[0-9]+"));`

Answer (score 2):

I do it as:

```
    File folder = new File(".");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            if (file.toString().endsWith(".sql")) {
                System.out.println(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("End!!");
```

Comment: Excellent Solution But you should add .toLowerCase() to your last "if" statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the what I wound up with. It uses a nice lambda expression that can be easily twisted to your own designs...

```
File folder = new File(FullPath);
String[] files = folder.list((lamFolder, lamName) -> lamName.matches("[0-9]+"));
if(files == null) {
    System.out.println("Stuff wrongly: no matching files found.");
} else {
    for(String file : files) {
        System.out.println("HOORAY: I found this "+ file);
    }
}
```