# Get certain FileName based on its extension Java

Tags: java, file

I want to get certain file from my path which is only with ".pdf" file . How can i achieve it ?

```
     File path = new File("C:\\Users\\theunique\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\APUassignment");
    File [] files = path.listFiles();

       for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    if (files[i].isFile()){ //this line weeds out other directories/folders
        System.out.println(files[i].getName());
    }
    }
```

my output result is

```
ModulesNumber.txt 
ModulesObjects.dat
number.txt
Objects.dat
OODJ-Exam-Nick.pdf
oodj-null-Joseph.pdf
```

I want it to be

```
OODJ-Exam-Nick
OODJ-null-Joseph
```

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of String? Because all you need is inside this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int index = files[i].getName().lastIndexOf(".");
String extension= files[i].getName().substring(index, files[i].getName().length());
if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf") {
    System.out.println(files[i].getName().subString(0, index));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you could use the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(files[i]);
String fileNameWithoutExtension = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(files[i]);
if(fileExtension.equals("pdf")){
    System.out.println(fileNameWithoutExtension);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`File.listFiles(FilenameFilter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FilenameFilter)).
See [Use of FilenameFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19933122/3453226).

```
File[] files = path.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        // Automatically weeds out directories
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf");
    }
});
// Why use an index?
for (File file : files) {
    System.out.println(file.getName());
}
```