# Need to upload only pdf or any doc type format in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to upload only pdf or any doc type files but .gif and .psd format is also getting added. I need to upload only supported file format.

```
resume_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MyProfileActivity.this, android.Manifest
                        .permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager
                        .PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission
                            .WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                } else {
                    Intent target = FileUtils.createGetContentIntent();
                    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Select File");
                    intent.setType("application/msword,application/pdf");
                    try {
                        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ignored) {

                    }
                }
            } else {
                Intent target = FileUtils.createGetContentIntent();
                Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Select File");
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ignored) {

                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932962/use-of-filenamefilter

Comment: Try using intent.setType(" file/* ");

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code snippet for that

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/pdf|application/msword");
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_DOC_REQUEST_CODE);
```

It's working for me hope it's works for you!

Comment: @Williams From which app you are picking the files? Cause some third party file managers don't support the mime-types provided by the intent.

Comment: In Es file Explorer its working but in default phone gallery its not working.It's getting added

Comment: @Williams, you can do nothing about it. The gallery ignores your restrictions I think. That is not your fault.

Comment: @Williams **Es file Explorer** exactly it's ignoring the mime-types. I had the similar issue. What you can do is that just add condition to check the file's extension at onActivityResult().