# Show only specific file types from android mobile device

Tags: android

I would like to display only the mp3 files from my mobile device, but there is an exception: The app crashes because there are no mp3 files on mobile device. How can I handle this case?

```
String path= "/storage/emulated/0";
File rootDir = newFile(path);
File[] files = rootDir.listFiles();
String[] filenames = new String[files.length];
for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
File file =files[i];
String filePath= file.getPath();
if(filePath.endsWith(".mp3"){
filenames[i] = files[i].getName();
}
else{
finishActivity(2);
}
```

Comment: maybe below link help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932962/use-of-filenamefilter

Comment: maybe below link help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932962/use-of-filenamefilter